# What does this reflexive typedef mean?

Tags: c++, typedef, systemd-journald

I was browsing the Systemd / Journald header files, and in `/usr/include/systemd/sd-journal.h`, I noticed this line of code:

```cpp
typedef struct sd_journal sd_journal;
```

It seems that the struct `sd_journal` is defined as... `sd_journal`. What does this reflexive / recursive `typedef` actually mean?

Comment: This is a C-ism.  Looking for a duplicate

Comment: `sd_journal` is defined as `struct sd_journal`. Makes a big difference in C.

Comment: In C the `sd_journal` in `struct sd_journal`, being the struct tag, is in the tag namespace; that’s separate from the global namespace, and the typedef creates a new name in the global namespace. In C++ this isn’t necessary.